# Alpinejs store bind to component variable

Tags: alpine.js

I have two Apine components `[app1, app2]` on change in `app1` component storing the date value in `Stores` and in `app2` component trying to show the stored date value. it is not showing on update.

Store Variable are not chained or bind component variables
[code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-austin-dgvhmq)

```js
<script>
      function app1(){
        return {
          date:'2023-07-23',
          itenary:'',
        }
      }
      Alpine.store('selected_itenary', app1().itenary);
    </script>
    <script>
      function app2(){
        return {
          start_date:'2023-07-23',
        }
      }
    </script>
```

```html
 <div x-data="app1()">
      <input x-model="date" type="text" class="w-48">
      <button class="rounded-md px-5 py-2 border border-gray-500" @click="$store.selected_itenary = date;">Click</button>
    </div>
    <div x-data="app2()">
        <div x-text="$store.selected_itenary"></div>
      </div>
```

How to bind store value in app2 component?

And also, is to correct/possible to bind only one Object entry to the store?

```js
 Alpine.store('selected_itenary', app1().itenary);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out in a codepen and got it working doing 2 things:

- Ensured the cdn script tag loading in alpinejs was `defer`red:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/3.12.1/cdn.js" defer></script>
```

- I changed the script code to use `Alpine.data`:

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () =>
    {        
        Alpine.data('app1', () => ({
        
          date:'2023-07-23',
          itenary:'2023-07-23',
        
        }));
        Alpine.store('selected_itenary', '2023-07-23');
    
        Alpine.data('app2', () => ({  
            start_date:'2023-07-23',
        }));         
    });
```

After which everything worked as expected.

Comment: Ya, thank you, your coding is working fine. I have one question. Why does the above code not work?

Comment: I'm not entirly sure, most likely because you hadn't deferred the loading, so then Alpine wasn't ready yet when the page loaded.

Comment: I have one more question. How can I subscribe changes in app1().itenary alone?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you try to explain in more detail what you want to achieve?